# A SQL query replace value in a row with NULL, if this value is equal to the value from the previous row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following sql query:

select supplier, name, date, turnover
 from turnover
 order by supplier

```
  supplier      name        date       turnover
  --------      ---------   ---------- ----------
       001      supplier1   01.01.2012     129,67
       001      supplier1   02.05.2012  12.145,89
       001      supplier1   03.07.2012   6.830,90 
       002      supplier2   01.01.2012     -11,55
       002      supplier2   03.09.2012   4.500,61
```

Is it possible to replace the repeating values with a NULL, so the resulting table looks like this (see below)?

```
  supplier      name        date       turnover
  --------      ---------   ---------- ----------
       001      supplier1   01.01.2012     129,67
                            02.05.2012  12.145,89
                            03.07.2012   6.830,90 
       002      supplier2   01.01.2012     -11,55
                            03.09.2012   4.500,61
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the analytic function `LAG` and the `NULLIF` function.  Something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select nullif(deptno,
  2                lag(deptno) over (order by deptno, ename)) formatted_deptno,
  3         ename
  4    from emp
  5*  order by deptno, ename
SQL> /

FORMATTED_DEPTNO ENAME
---------------- ----------
              10 CLARK
                 KING
                 MILLER
              20 ADAMS
                 FORD
                 JONES
                 SCOTT
                 SMITH
              30 ALLEN
                 BLAKE
                 JAMES
                 MARTIN
                 TURNER
                 WARD

14 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `row_number`:

```
select case row when 1 then supplier_orig else null end as supplier,
  case row when 1 then name_orig else null end as name,
  date, turnover
from (
  select supplier AS supplier_orig, name AS name_orig, date, turnover,
  row_number() over (partition by supplier order by date) as row
  from turnover 
)
order by supplier_orig, date
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/41908/17)